# Unable to create WebJob in Azure portal

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

I'm manually trying to add a web job in azure by file upload and it's failing with a very unhelpful error.

I was initially trying to upload a console app as a web job by uploading a zip of the bin folder and alternatively a zip of the contents of the bin folder (i.e. the root of the zip varies) and it was failing.

I decided to try with a simple test.bat file that basically had nothing in it and it still fails indicating a potential problem with azure itself.

[image]

I tried looking for some logging or detailed explanation of the error but cant find anything anywhere to help me diagnose the problem.

How do I overcome this problem without using visual studio's inbuilt publish to azure

Comment: What browser you are using, please try with chrome. And if this don't work, you could try some other ways to deploy.https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Reporting-WebJobs-issues#how-are-you-deploying-your-webjobs

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your web app is Windows based, not Linux. I was able to upload a .bat file that simply contained `ECHO "Hello World"`

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem was some functionality of the Azure Portal only working in Chrome browser.

Not a good look for microsoft when even backyard operators can support multiple browsers and Microsoft cannot.

Comment: Which browser were you using?